# Is there any API to detect AWS stack name, where Lambda is running

Tags: aws-lambda

I need to know stack name or at least function name in the lambda handler decorator code.
Any idea ? boto3.client('cloudformation') gettesr and describe function needs stack name as parameter. Lambda context is still None at that point.
Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

If you need the stack name you should pass it in as an environment variable to the function. Those values are always available. You can use `!Ref AWS::StackName` in the environment definition. Something like this:

```
  MyFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      FunctionName: My-Function
      # other properties left out for brevity
      Environment:
        Variables:
          StackName: !Ref AWS::StackName
```

Comment: That's what I did meanwhile. But then I have [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60269108/how-to-automatically-put-environment-variable-to-all-lambdas-created-in-my-cdk-p) - how to update automatically all lambda's.